# How to Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files

Tags: ros, eigen, macosx, osx, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I entered this command:

```
cd /Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros && /Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

I get the following error:

```
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I tried to follow the guide for installing the eigen but apparently it was unsuccessful. I have these in `/usr/local/eigen` :

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:~ mona$ cd /usr/local/eigen
Monas-MacBook-Pro:eigen mona$ ls
CMakeLists.txt              build_dir
COPYING.BSD             cmake
COPYING.GPL             debug
COPYING.LGPL                demos
COPYING.MINPACK             doc
COPYING.MPL2                eigen3.pc.in
COPYING.README              failtest
CTestConfig.cmake           lapack
CTestCustom.cmake.in            scripts
Eigen                   signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
INSTALL                 test
bench                   unsupported
blas
```

And I have followed these steps in `INSTALL` file:

```
cd build_dir
cmake source_dir
make install
```

However when I enter `eigen` it is not recognized.

I need to get this fixed for this step of installing ROS on OSX:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I am not an OSX guru, so if you are want to help me, it is best suggested to tell me how to set paths or where the files you want me to modify are located.

** I used destination path for eigen3:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/eigen3
make install
```

and now I have these items after `make install` :

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:build_dir mona$ ls /usr/local/eigen3/include/eigen3/
Eigen                   unsupported
signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
Monas-MacBook-Pro:build_dir mona$ ls /usr/local/eigen3/include/eigen3/Eigen/
Array           Householder     QR          StdDeque
Cholesky        IterativeLinearSolvers  QtAlignedMalloc     StdList
CholmodSupport      Jacobi          SPQRSupport     StdVector
Core            LU          SVD         SuperLUSupport
Dense           LeastSquares        Sparse          UmfPackSupport
Eigen           MetisSupport        SparseCholesky      src
Eigen2Support       OrderingMethods     SparseCore
Eigenvalues     PaStiXSupport       SparseLU
Geometry        PardisoSupport      SparseQR
```

Yet I don't know where is the executable for eigen3 and how to set path for cmake.

Thanks a bunch,
Mona Jalal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215080/how-to-add-the-installation-prefix-of-%22eigen3%22-to-cmake_prefix_path-or-set-------%22eigen3_dir%22-to-a-directory-containing-one-of-the-above-files/) by [lamiastella](https://answers.ros.org/users/23430/lamiastella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tormod Haugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/23774/tormod-haugene/) on 2016-02-28**:
Hi! I am having the exact same issue as you. Did you ever solve it?

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-04-18**:
have you been able to solve it?
I stil have the same issue

**Comment by [Tormod Haugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/23774/tormod-haugene/) on 2016-07-21**:
I have not been able to instal ROS on OSX yet. It seems the OSX version is having some issues at the moment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We (the ROS community) provide a CMake module for Eigen, but it is provided under the name `Eigen` but it is deprecated in Jade:

https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules#eigen-deprecated

But the package you're compiling is not using that deprecated module and is failing because it is looking for the Eigen provided `Eigen3` CMake module. So the problem is likely that the version of Eigen you installed on your machine does not have this `Eigen3` CMake module. Older versions of Eigen did not ship it. If you installed Eigen with Homebrew then it might be a packaging problem with Eigen in Homebrew. The Jade migration guide has a suggest way that packages should find Eigen to avoid disruption in the mean time:

http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration#Eigen_CMake_Module_in_cmake_modules

It seems the package you're trying to compile (`pcl_ros`?) is not doing this or is doing it incorrectly. If it were following the suggestion then it would have "fallen" back on the `FindEigen.cmake` cmake module provided by the `cmake_modules` ROS package.

It could be that something else is going on that's causing the issue, but that's my take on it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this error because I had a newer version of cmake installed.
libeigen3-dev had installed FindEigen3.cmake in usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules (the default Ubuntu 14.04 cmake) but not the other cmake versions. Since catkin_make defaults to latest cmake, it can't find the module.
In my case, simply copying FindEigen3.cmake into usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules fixed the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Jacob Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/23801/jacob-lambert/) with karma: 63 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-01**:
Or you can create symbolic link to the file using `ln -s` command.

**Comment by [Stanley HU](https://answers.ros.org/users/37553/stanley-hu/) on 2018-09-19**:
i got the same error after i upgrade my cmake from 2. to 3. . But there is no such a file called FindEigen3.cmake in my PC, what the reason behind it? Thanks for your answering.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-09-19**:
@Stanley HU try `dpkg -l | grep -i eigen3` to find out whether you have eigen3 library installed.

**Comment by [Stanley HU](https://answers.ros.org/users/37553/stanley-hu/) on 2018-09-19**:
<ii  libeigen3-dev                                         3.2.0-8                                              all          lightweight C++ template library for linear algebra>
This seems i already have eigen3 library installed? but i still don't have FindEigen3.cmake file

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-09-19**:
Have you looked in `/usr/share/cmake-VERSION/Modules`?

**Comment by [Stanley HU](https://answers.ros.org/users/37553/stanley-hu/) on 2018-09-19**:
even there is no cmake folder under /share, anyway i search it in whole pc but i still cannot find it

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-09-19**:
@Stanley HU how did you install the eigen3 library? Can you reinstall it?

**Comment by [Stanley HU](https://answers.ros.org/users/37553/stanley-hu/) on 2018-09-19**:
sorry, i found it, problem is solved,Thanks very much

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2019-02-19**:
@l4ncelot I have FindEigen3.cmake in my cmake-2.8 folder. But I still get this error. Any idea how to solve it?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2019-02-19**:
@surabhi96 do you have newer version of cmake in `/usr/share/` directory? If you do, cmake will try to access the newer version, so it won't find the `FindEigen3.cmake` file in your `cmake-2.8` directory.